# bootstrap-datetimepicker error el formato de fecha, Asp Mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Tengo en una vista un inputbox sobre el cual estoy usando bootstrap-datetimepicker para capturar la fecha, este DTP tiene el formato 'YYYY/MM/DD':

`<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format:'YYYY/MM/DD', locale:'es-MX'});
        });
</script>`

cuando inicia la vista el controlador envía un valor de fecha como '10/06/2016' pero el problema es que la vista me muestra '0010/06/20'.

Si cambio el formato en el script, la fecha que recibe la vista por medio del controller se muestra correctamente, pero surge un problema al seleccionar un valor del DateTimePicker ya que cualquier fecha que superior al día 12 me lo toma como invalido...

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format:'DD/MM/YYYY', locale:'es-MX'});
    });
</script>`
```

¿Como solucionar este problema de formatos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el controlador debes cambiar el formato de fecha, de tal manera te ahorras el problema en el cliente, aquí te dejo una lista de ejemplos:

```
// números de mes/día sin o con ceros:
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", dt);            // "3/9/2008"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"

// nombres día/mes
String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dt);    // "Do, Mar 9, 2008"
String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", dt);  // "Domingo, Marzo 9, 2008"

// dos/cuatro dígitos para el año
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", dt);            // "03/09/08"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"
```

Extraído de: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

**Actualización**

Considerando el comentario de @jose luis garcia, en el Modelo también se puede definir de la siguiente manera:

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
 public DateTime CampoDeFecha{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @fredyfx, agregue el atributo DisplayFormat con el formato deseado y funciono perfectamente.

Comment: de nada, sigue asi! dale con todo el power 2.0 al desarrollo!

Comment: aunque lo ideal sería que lo utilizaras en el modelo como te explican y agregando demás  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)], de esta manera en la edición también te saldría. Al definirlo en el modelo te ahorras tener que escribir el mismo código en el controlador cada vez que necesites de una fecha